# fonts appear small in samsung Galaxy Android 2.1

Tags: android

I have written an application which is working fine in Emulator . But when  I install the same in Android device Samsung Galaxy 2.1 , the fonts appear very small compared to the fonts in Emulator. How to solve this issue ? How to make my application to make it appear similar in both emulator and device. 
can anyone help me in solving this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you've used regular pixels (px) as your font dimension. Use scaled pixels (sp) instead to get a consistent font appearance across multiple densities.

Comment: also entire application appears very small as lot of space is left at the right side.Also how to set these sized pixels through code

Comment: @Android_programmer_camera: For the font set it by using android:textSize in your XML layout. To answer your question about the position of all your other elements I'd need to take a look at your layout.

Comment: My question is I am populating an TextView dynamically through code not from XML. I am creating TextView in .java file and need to set TextSize by setTextSize() method, but how can we differentiate b/w the value given to this method will be of type px or sp.

Comment: @Android_programmer_camera: if you use textview.setTextSize(10) it will set the font size of that TextView to 10 sp.