# Small fonts in mobile website

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, web

I have developed a mobile website and it shows perfectly to me in Android and IPhone emulator. However, when I try to view it on an Android phone or IPhone, it displays the website as a normal desktop website viewed on phone with very high widths and fonts appearing very small. The issue gets resolved, if I double click/tap on my screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I got this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132954/fonts-appear-small-in-samsung-galaxy-android-2-1)..but not much sure about it

Comment: What's the DOCTYPE of your documents?

Comment: @ceejayoz the urls is http://35webs.com

Comment: @TedHopp.what should be the correct doctype?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add a meta tag named "viewport" see sample below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
</head>
<body style='background-color:white;font-family:Arial,Tahoma,Verdana;'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep, they all use same browser (WebKit)