# Responsive site scaling down on mobile rather than adjusting

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

I'm getting some weird behaviour that I'm not sure why it's happening.

I'm building out an site. When running this locally in Chrome and Safari, it displays fine, everything adjusts as you'd expect. However, in responsive mode, and when viewed directly on mobile, the entire site is scaling down in size to fit. By this I mean the entire site every element all reducing in size to to be shown as it looks at desktop size.

I'm using Bourbon/Neat, with a bit of flexbox here and there, which I have done many a times before. I've just never experienced this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You likely need to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

to the `<head>` section of your html

Comment: Sorry, should have added that I do indeed have that!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?  I would be able to help if so.

Comment: Actually, you've got the right answer. I had added the viewport meta tag, but was viewing the site from an old version! Thought I was going crazy. Latest version pushed up and all is good again! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Jordan's answer is in the right direction but it didn't work for me.

There is another post here on Stackoverflow that has a more comprehensive meta tag, that fixed it for me:

[Small fonts in mobile website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731793/small-fonts-in-mobile-website)